# Using data from one component in another in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, components, prop

I made a counting app that when you click you level and get gold, but how do use the data in another component? For example, I want to use this.state.max in another component.

Sorry, I'm quite new to React

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import darkalien from '../assets/darkgray__0000_idle_1.png';
import darkalien2 from '../assets/darkgray__0033_attack_3.png';
import darkalien3 from '../assets/darkgray__0039_fire_5.png';

var style = {
  color: 'black',
  fontSize: 20
};
var style2 ={
  color: '#daa520',
  fontSize: 20
}

export default class Home extends Component{
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
        i: 0,
        j: 1,
        k: 0,
        max: 10,
        maxf: 2,
        maxi: 10

     }
 }
onClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var level = this.state.j;
  this.setState({i: this.state.i + 1});
  this.setState({k: this.state.k + 1});

  if(this.state.i >= this.state.max){
      this.setState({j: this.state.j + 1});
      this.setState({i: this.state.i});
      this.setState({k: this.state.k});
      if(this.state.j === this.state.maxf){
          this.setState({maxf: this.state.maxf + 1});
          this.setState({max: this.state.max + 10});
      }
    this.setState({i: this.state.i = 0});
  }
}
render(){
    return(
    <header>
        <div className="container" id="maincontent" tabIndex="-1">
           <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-12">
                <div className="intro-text">

                        <p className="name" style={style} id="demo3">Level {this.state.j}</p>
                        <p className="name" id="demo4" style={style}>Points: {this.state.k}</p>
                        <p className="name" style={style2} id="demo5">Gold: {this.state.max}</p>

                    <img id="picture" className="img-responsive" src={darkalien} alt="alien-img" onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} height="150" width="150"/>

                    <progress id="demo2" value={this.state.i} max={this.state.max}></progress>
                    <h1 className="name">Click me!</h1>
                    <hr className="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></hr>
                   <span className="skills">Gain Experience &#9733; Get Coins &#9733; Purchase Armor</span>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    );
}
}
```

I want to use the this.state.max in my store component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import blaster from '../assets/blaster_1.png';
import blaster2 from '../assets/blaster_3.png';
import alienSuit from '../assets/predatormask__0000_idle_1.png';
import alienHair from 
'../assets/alien_predator_mask_0007_hair_profile.png';
import Home from '../components/Home';


export default class Store extends Component{
render(){
    return(
        <section id="portfolio">
        <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-12">
            <h3>Armor and Weapon Store<span>  **Gold:{this.state.j}**  </span></h3>
        </div>

        </div>
        <div className="row text-center">

        <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-6 hero-feature">
            <div className="thumbnail">
                <img src={blaster} alt=""/>
                <div className="caption">
                    <h3>Reggae Blaster</h3>

                    <p>
                        <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">Buy Now!</a> <a href="#" className="btn btn-default">More Info</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Pass it as a prop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve the data held in your state by creating a function in the class that returns that data. For example

```
export default class Home extends Component{
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
        i: 0,
        j: 1,
        k: 0,
        max: 10,
        maxf: 2,
        maxi: 10

     }
 }

 getMax(){
   return this.state.max
 }

 //Rest of your code...
}
```

You would then call getMax by defining a new instance of Home with

```
var home = new Home
```

then call the getMax function wherever you need your this.state.max

```
var max = home.getMax()
```

However as the other answers have said I would recommend looking at another form of state management, my personal favorite being Redux.

Answer (score 3):

React's architecture is specifically designed to not have cross-component dependencies. If you had a lot of those dependencies you would find yourself quickly in a 'hairball' that would make code maintenance very difficult.

However if you want to manage an App state in a controlled way I would recommend to consider using a state container (especially if your app gets more complex). You could look into Redux for example and potentially also use the server / database to store more long time data. Here is an [article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/06/07/react-state-vs-redux-state/) explaining a different categorization of states.

And of course - Here's the link to the [must read me](http://redux.js.org/) of Redux and the [basic tutorial](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/), which should help with your use case.